# How to prevent javascript to be loaded multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am in middle of a problem. I have made an application in which I have assigned DIV to be loaded by ajax. Each of the DIV corresponds to a specific module (like one module related to product details, another DIV related to pricing and availability ). Each module is a URL.

DIV1 --- for product details
DIV2 --- pricing
DIV3 --- catogorisation

All these DIVs are asynchronously loaded. In category module, i have special javascript control for category browsing as a tree view.

The problem I am facing, if I place javascript library in the main page, the control does not show up. and If i place the library in DIV3's URL source page, then it loaded multiple times and hangs my application.

My question is how I can prevent this library to be loaded multiple times if user refreshes the DIV again and again.

Or if it seems a design issue, can you please give your suggestions for proper design. I am keen to know how to unload the library. I am java programmer and thinks in that way. I may have some wrong understanding of javascript working

Thanks in advance 
Jujhar

Answer (score 1):

Javascript code doesn't have to be executed only when you load a script tag. If you just put the relevant code in a function and call it from the success callback in your ajax function, you can easily avoid this problem.

1. Move `<script>` to html body
2. Wrap relevant code in function

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  //... your code
}
```

3. Call `myFunction` in your ajax success callback

Ajax

```
$.get("/url", function(data) {
  //add div to page
  myFunction();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Will for your time. It makes sense and I have just implemented it.
Just one more question in my mind.
In    myfFunction()    if I am initialization object or I am creating a object (like creating a Data table ) , if user refresh the DIV, wont it create a duplicate object ? In 1st ajax call datatable object will be created and if user refresh agaim the same myFunction(). code will be executed & creating a duplicate object. Sorry asking this dumb question, I can include code to check whether DOM object already created before creating new one. Just keen to know if there is any other way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by refreshing a div. If you refresh the page, everything while be cleared from the page so there won't be any duplicates though.